# Why does this code cause a deadlock? (producer-consumer model)

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

I'm trying to design 5 producers and single consumer model. I have just learned how to design the model from [Producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), Wikipedia. But I have hard time avoiding the dead lock. I don't understand why this code cause the dead lock.

Here is consumer. (Assume that single process executes this code. and all semaphores and shared memory are already initialized.)

```
int main()
{
Shared_Data       =   (shared_data*)Shared_Address; // this is a shared memory. 
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sprintf(debugbuf, "%ld, filled downsem, %dth loop\n", (long)getpid(), i);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, debugbuf, strlen(debugbuf));
        sem_wait(filled);   // try to access to the shared memory.
                            // if the shared memory is empty, consumer waits for it to be filled with pid and state.


        read.isIdle        =   I_AM_IDLE;
        read.WrittenByPid  =   Shared_Data->WrittenByPid;

        sprintf(debugbuf, "%ld, empty upsem\n", (long)getpid());
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, debugbuf, strlen(debugbuf));


        sem_post(empty);
    }
}
```

Here is producer. (Assume that five processes execute this code and all semaphores and shared memory are already initialized.)

```
int main()
{
    sprintf(debugbuf, "%ld, empty downsem\n", (long)getpid());
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, debugbuf, strlen(debugbuf));
                        // only one child process have access to here.
    sem_wait(empty);    // another child process doen't have access to here,
                        // untill parent process reads the shared memory.


    sprintf(writebuf, "%s %ld process is forked.\n", Get_CurrentTime(date), (long)getpid());
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, writebuf, strlen(writebuf));
    Put_itsState_into_SharedMemory(getpid(), I_AM_IDLE, YES_Virgin);


    sprintf(debugbuf, "%ld, filled upsem\n", (long)getpid());
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, debugbuf, strlen(debugbuf));


    sem_post(filled);
}
```

But I have the following result.

```
32685, filled downsem, 0th loop
32687, empty downsem
32687, filled upsem
32685, empty upsem
32685, filled downsem, 1th loop
32690, empty downsem
32689, empty downsem
32691, empty downsem
32688, empty downsem
[stuck in for-loop]
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: what is `filled`? What is `empty`? How do you declare and initialize these variables? Also, while the consumer wait for `filled` the producer waits for `empty`.

Comment: `filled` semaphore is initially 0. `empty` semaphore is initially 1.

Comment: How many item can be in the buffer? one?

Comment: all producer and single consumer share single structure `shared_data`. they share only one buffer.

Comment: Yes, I have created child process using `fork`.

Comment: Does it always deadlock or only sometimes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30907/discussion-between-raphael-ahrens-and-inherithandle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check, what the return value of `sem_wait` is.

If you are in the `sem_wait` function and an interrupt comes in, then `sem_wait` will return  an error unequal to 0.
Then you need to check if an interrupt happened, with `errno`.

Since you use `fork` you can get the `SIGCHLD` interrupt when one child process exits.

Comment: To be more specific, `sem_wait` will return with `-1` on error, always.

Comment: What if I'd like to sleep again in `sem_wait` although I'm in `sem_wait` and an interrupt comes in?

Comment: Then, Does `sem_post` not increment semaphore variable on error?

Comment: @inherithandle Loop over the `sem_wait`, break out of the loop if `sem_wait` returns zero or `errno` is not `EINTR`?

Comment: @inherithandle Also, the semaphore is _not_ touched on error. Read [a manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_wait.html).